# Is there a difference between an string and an ASCII string in C?

Tags: c, cpu-architecture

In my computer architecture course we are being asked to write a program that takes in a pointer to an 'ASCII' string as one of our function arguments. Being unaware that there may be different variations of strings, I would have just declared an array of characters as usual, but how would someone declare an array of characters that are specific to an ASCII string. Please provide an example of a pointer to an ASCII string declaration. Please comment below if anything mentioned was unclear.

Comment: All ASCII strings are strings; the assignment probably says that so you know you *don't* have to make sure your program works with UTF-8 strings, or UTF-16 strings, or EBCDIC (!) strings.

Comment: According to the C11 spec, your choices are `char`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t`, and `char32_t`. Specifying an 'ASCII' string means that a simple `char` array should work.

Answer (score 1):

Every string in C is ASCII. Standard ASCII characters are 7-bits wide. Your professor just want to emphasis you should use **byte** array to store the string. Unlike let's say `UTF-8` which can use up to 4 bytes for encoding a certain characters.

`char *str = "example";`

Comment: C programs can deal with non-ASCII strings, and do so all the time.  Most modern GNU/Linux implementation of POSIX commands like `grep` are written in C and work with UTF-8 strings (if you use a utf8 locale).  Also, ASCII characters are 8 bits wide, but only have 7 significant bits.  The high bit is always cleared, but it's part of the ASCII encoding, not just padding introduced by storing the values in an array of C `char` / `int8_t`.